# `check_conditionals': Passing string to be evaluated in :if and :unless conditional options is not supported (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

when I run rails server in development mode it will run. But if I tried to run RAILS_ENV=production rails server it is showing some errors I am unable to resolve it.
This is my error logs:-

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.0 application starting in production 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:355:in `check_conditionals': Passing string to be evaluated in :if and :unless conditional options is not supported. Pass a symbol for an instance method, or a lambda, proc or block, instead. (ArgumentError)
    from /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:301:in `initialize'
    from /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:289:in `new'
    from /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:289:in `build'
    from /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:672:in `block in set_callback'
    from /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:671:in `map'
    from /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:671:in `set_callback'
    from /home/sharat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activemodel-5.2.0/lib/active_model/callbacks.rb:131:in `block in _define_before_model_callback'
```

My Application controller look

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  self.responder = ApplicationResponder
  respond_to :html
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
    flash[:warning] = 'Resource not found.'
    redirect_back_or root_path
  end
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to role_based_path, :alert => exception.message
  end

 def redirect_back_or(path)
    redirect_to request.referer || path
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    role_based_path
  end

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username, :role])

  end

end
```

Comment: In your models, you have specified a string to `if:` or `unless:` in one or more callbacks e.g. `before_save :do_something, if: '2 + 3 > 0'`. Instead, use a symbol (if the string part is a method) or a proc e.g. `before_save :do_something, if: -> { 2 + 3 > 0 }`. This is the best i can explain with no code in your question. :)

Comment: @JagdeepSingh this is where I have if block. How I need to change this

Comment: Anywhere in your models?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh initial the project was developed using rails 5 afterward we have upgraded to 5.2. is this dependencies issues?

Comment: hi jagdeep I have used gem invoicing as per there docs, I have used act_as method when I removed that method it is working